# Jenkins - How to pick Kubernetes server to deploy to?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, configuration

I have installed the Kubernetes plugin as well as added 2 kubernetes slave nodes in the `Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure system -> Cloud`.

Then when adding jobs I can't see a place to configure the target environment. There's simply no tabs as seen for example here:

[image]

Here's what it looks on my job configuration:

[image]